# How to create a product grid with equal spacing and three items per row?

Tags: css, sass

Apologies if the question is already asked but the past solutions didn't help me.

I'm trying to have a product grid like this but I can't figure it out how to do it only for three items.

https://i.ibb.co/gVtHZW1/Screenshot-48.png

With equal spacing around each item and only 3 items per row. But reduced to only one item per row on mobile view. Both flex or grid solutions may work.

```
//Parent    

<div className="product-list-inner" >
  {
    product.map(item => <ProductItem id={item.id} item={item} />)
  }
</div>

//Child

<div className="product_item">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I said none of the solutions helped me so what is your problem mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.product-list-inner{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(300px, 1fr) );
    @media screen( max-width: 768px){
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```